# How to take data by clicking checkbox to a next page in android

Tags: android, listview, checkedlistbox

I have a list view with heading- name , id and phone number
along with that i have list of check-boxes, What I want is when I check the checkboxes in there corresponding rows it picks the id and name of that corresponding row  and pass the data to other page by click menu .
Steps to do
1. check multiple checkbox
2.by counting the  number of checkboxes checked in the listview
3. and then sending the data of each n every corresponding row whose checkbox is checked  to next page by click menu button on that  page

how can i do that ?  can anybody Give me the ideas :)

```
private class SummaryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    public SummaryAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Item> items){
        super(context,textViewResourceId,items);
        this.items=items;
    } 
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        View v=convertView;

        if(v==null){
            LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v=vi.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
        }
        Item o=items.get(position); 
        if(o!=null){
            final TextView idView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemId);
            final TextView captionView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemCaption);
            final TextView phoneView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemPhone);
            final TextView typeView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemType);

             chkReport=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkReport);
            //TextView t5=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.AdvanceSearchVisitID);


             chkReport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
             if(idView!=null){
                idView.setText(""+o.getId());
            }


            if(captionView!=null){
                captionView.setText(o.getCaption());
            }   

            if(phoneView!=null){
                phoneView.setText(o.getPhone());
            }

            if(typeView!=null){
                typeView.setText(o.getType());
            }

            captionView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    fnNameClicked(idView.getText().toString(),typeView.getText().toString());
                }

            }); 


        /*  chkReport.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,boolean arg1) {
                    if(arg0.isChecked()){
                    fnCheckChanged(idView.getText().toString(),captionView.getText().toString(),arg1,arg0); 
                    }

                }
            });*/

        }
        return v;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

boolean result=super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

menu.add(0,menu_1,1,R.string.menu_track_sales_force);



menu.add(0,menu_2,2,R.string.menu_select_all);
    menu.add(0,menu_3,3,R.string.menu_unselect_all);
    return result;
}
    @

Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){       
        case menu_1:
            //fnSave();  
            boolean bFlg=false;
            boolean bMobile=false;
            String sPhoneMsg="";


        Integer listCount=lv.getCount();
        Integer iListCount=0;


        if(bNoMoreRecords==true){
            iListCount=listCount;
        }
        else{
            iListCount=listCount-1;
        }

        for(Integer xx=0;xx<iListCount;xx++){
            if(lv.isItemChecked(xx)){
                bFlg=true;

                if("".equals(m_result.get(xx).getId())){
                    sPhoneMsg="Id of user "+m_result.get(xx).getCaption().toString()+" is not available, please remove it from selection.";
                    bMobile=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(bMobile==true){
            MsgBox1(ctx,sPhoneMsg);
            return true;
        }
        if(bFlg==false){
            MsgBox1(ctx,"Please select atleast one ID !");
            return true;
        }

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");

        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems=lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int checkedItemsCount=checkedItems.size();

        if(bNoMoreRecords==false){
            if(listCount==checkedItemsCount){
                checkedItemsCount=checkedItemsCount-1;
            }
        }

        boolean isFirstSelected = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; ++i) {
            int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
            boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);

            if(isChecked){
                if(!isFirstSelected){
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                if("".equals(m_result.get(position).getId())){}
                else{

                    sb.append(m_result.get(position).getId());
                }
                isFirstSelected=false;
            }
        }

        String ss=sb.toString();

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,SRSDTrackForceDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("UserID",ss);
        startActivity(intent);

        //StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("Selection: ");
    //  SparseBooleanArray checkedItems=lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
        //if (checkedItems==null || checkedItems.size()==0){
        //  MsgBox2(ctx,"Please select atleast one ID !");
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Please select atleast one ID !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  return true;
        MsgBox1(ctx,"Tracking queried successfully !");
        //Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case menu_2:
        fnSelectAll();
        return true;
    case menu_3:
        fnUnSelectAll();
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

```
private void fnSelectAll(){
        Integer listCount=lv.getCheckedItemPosition();
        //listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(Integer xx=0;xx<listCount;xx++){
            lv.setItemChecked(xx,true);
        }
        //listView
    }
    private void fnUnSelectAll(){
        Integer listCount=lv.getCheckedItemPosition();
        //listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(Integer xx=0;xx<listCount;xx++){
            lv.setItemChecked(xx,false);
        }
        //listView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the issue is here. Just have an array of flag of size same as your list size. This boolean array would contain checked state of each item in list. On click of menu button, just itterate through this array, and on value true add the list item(id, name) to a temporary arraylist or arrayList and put that list on intent starting another activity.

Comment: Welll theorticall xplanation is always bad can u help me in codee

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html
Under the Index of
7.2.  Rows interacting with the data model